# How does Machvise even hit anyone?

Tags: one-piece

In the Dressrosa Arc, we see Machvise fight. His fighting style is focused around his Devil Fruit, the Ton-Ton Fruit, which allows him to change his own weight (up to a weight of 10000 tons!) with him jumping up in the air and then falling down on top of people.

What I truly cannot understand is how he is even able to hit anyone! One Piece is a universe where people are fast enough to smack cannon-balls out of the air and dodge bullets, how are they unable to just get out of the damn way when they see him jump up!?!?

Even falling from a mere 20 meters will take about 2 seconds, long enough for a real-life person to see where he will fall and get out of the way. And Machvise tends to jump a lot higher than that, sometimes what seems like 100 meters up, which would take 4.5 seconds to fall down from!!

Honestly, I feel that his Fruit is far more suited for a fighting style that focuses on wrestling (and he even has the big, burly body structure that would work well in wrestling). Just run in, and as soon as he gets a good grip he makes sure to "fall over" on top of the person (or at least on top of whatever part he managed to grab) while adjusting his weight to a couple hundred tons. If he does that when holding an arm, he would tear it clean off the body! Way more effective than "jump and hope to hit"

Answer (score 2):

Changing his weight at will implies being able to lower it to close to nothing too. That is probably the technique he uses to reach dozens of meters in a single jump before increasing it greatly again to fall back with mighty power.

While falling, he could also lower his weight again to the weight of a feather and use the large surface of his body to glide sideways to reach any fleeing enemy. This is what a falcon in free fall does, precisely reaching his moving target with the fine tuning of his wings.

Using this, he can reach great velocities he would otherwise never reach with his legs only, running after his opponent in a more "traditional" wrestling style.

Comment: A good idea, though not once does anything indicate that he's moving in any horizontal direction once he starts falling. Given the extreme physical strength achievable in One Piece, it's not strange if he could just jump that high on his own though. Food for though; We do have a similar fruit, Miss Valentine's Kilo-Kilo Fruit, which lets her "adjust her weight between 1 and 10000 kg". With Machvise having the Ton-Ton Fruit, and his highest confirmed weight being 10000 tons, maybe the lightest he can be is 1 ton (reasonable considering his body size)

Comment: I did not say he moves horizontally, i suggested he probably can. And that may let his opponents feel it is pointless to run away, he'll catch them up. They are all rather large and slow by the way (Franky, Hajrudin the giant). As for his lower weight, Frankly wonders about it in chapter 735: "What the hell are you? First you float, then you smash". I can't imagine any ton-heavy item will float, even in one piece.